# Conversion of ByteArrayInputStream.toString results in warning Inefficient conversion from ByteArrayOutputStream

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, outputstream, bytearrayoutputstream

I have a `Spring Boot` application that converts the XML to JSON. The conversion is done by calling another `JAVA application` internally and passing some information. The implementation of the called application is out of my control and I do not have access to make any changes to it.

The called `Java Application` requires a `OutputStream` so I am using the `ByteArrayOutputStream` and passing it within the method. After receiving the output I am converting the `OutputStream` to `String`. During the conversion, I am running into the warning `Inefficient conversion from ByteArrayOutputStream`.

I wanted to know how can I fix this warning. I researched a bit and found that we need to pass the size of `ByteArrayOutputStream` but in my case I am not aware how much size it can have because it would depend on the size of the input XML that I am giving. So I am unable to predict it and set it.

Can someone please guide me on what I can do within my `Spring Boot` application `ByteArrayOutputStream` so as to fix the warning that I receive in my `Intellij IDE`:
`Inefficient conversion from ByteArrayOutputStream`

Following is my code sample:

```
final InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(xmlEvents.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
final var output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
new Converter().convert(inputStream, new Handler<>(new Validator(), new StreamCollector(output)));
return new String(output.toByteArray());
```

I am getting the warning for the line:
`new String(output.toByteArray())`

Comment: You should see a fix suggested by IntelliJ - `output.toString(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)`.

Comment: @Sweeper Thanks a lot. I am not sure how I missed seeing that. Thanks a lot for the response. This worked for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The explanation for this warning is that

```
  new String(output.toByteArray());
```

creates a `byte[]` from the contents of the `ByteArrayOutputStream`, then creates a `String` from the `byte[]`.  That is doing an unnecessary copy of the data.

The fix<sup>1</sup> suggested by Intellij is:

```
 output.toString(StandardCharsets.UTF_8).
```

which creates the `String` in a single operation without creating an intermediate `byte[]`.

How does it do this?

Well `toString()` is passing the `ByteArrayOutputStream`'s internal `byte[]` buffer to the `String` constructor.  By contrast, `output.toByteArray()` is copying the buffer to a new `byte[]` ... so that the caller cannot interfere with the actual buffer's contents.

---

<sup>1 - In fact the suggested fix doesn't have identical semantics to your original code.  The fix uses a specific character set for (UTF-8) converting the bytes to a string.  Your original code uses the platform's default character set.  In context, it looks like the fix is *more correct* than the original ... since the bytes seem to have started out as UTF-8.  However I guess that the converter *could* be mapping the bytes from one encoding to another behind the scenes.</sup>